# Application.Current.Properties - System.AggregateException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get some data from Application.Current.Properties storage. Unfortunately, any time I want to use this Dictionary, I see this error:

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

And in details I found this:

> {"Error in line 1 position 206. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value' contains data of the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfstring' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfstring' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."}

It seems like I tried to save some non-string data to Application.Current.Properties. Unfortunately I can't run .Clear() method to erease all data, bacause I receive this error any time I'm trying to access this property.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as its name suggests AggregateException, is just a container for one or more exceptions which may be thrown when using PLINQ or TPL.

As such exceptions may be thrown on different threads and may also occur concurrently, the system automatically catches and rethrows them within an AggregateException wrapper to ensure that they all get reported in one place. The exceptions themselves are exposed via the InnerExceptions property.

You can catch an AggregateException and check which exceptions it actually contains with code such as the following:

```
try
{
    // perform some parallel operation
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    string messages = "";

    foreach(Exception ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
    {
        messages += ex.Message + "\r\n";    
    }

    MessageBox.Show(messages);
}
```

So I suggest you do this to see what is causing the problem

Comment: Your code simply showed me what I already known (and it's pasted in question details of stack overflow). The problem is: I still don't have a clue what to do next. How to add 'Arrayofstring' to the list of known types and why the hell I need to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove your app from your device, Settings - Applications- Uninstall, this works for me. The Auth Object was crash in debug mode.Clean and Rebuild can be Helpfull to.